# Artificial generation of cpu load in Java

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage

Is there a simple way to generate a constant CPU load in Java? Like generate CPU load at 60%.

Comment: When you want a constant CPU load, does your requirement apply to multi-core CPUs as well? It is not easy (and is more or less impossible) to obtain CPU affinity in Java.

Comment: No single CPU, in particular I want to test it in Android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tested this, but it might roughly work, to make your application work and sleep in the correct ratio. Something like (pseudocode):

```
load = 60;  
do forever
  time = current_system_time_ms() + load
  while (current_system_time_ms() < time)
     // just consume some time for 60 ms 
  end

  SLEEP(100 - load);  // sleep for 40 ms
end
```

Ok, you asked for a simple way, but ... :)

Comment: Make span 100 and then make the measure current CPU be currentTimeMillis or something. Sleep for 40millis and then stay looping for 60.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli thinking about it more deeply raises doubts it would work. I think you are right. I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Kind of late to the party, but just wanted to share that I created a small open-source client library called [FakeLoad](https://github.com/msigwart/fakeload) which can be used to generate different kinds of system load like CPU, memory, and disk I/O on the fly.

For instance, generating a CPU load of 60% for 30 seconds with FakeLoad can be done like this:

```
// Creation
FakeLoad fakeload = FakeLoads.create()
    .lasting(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .withCpu(60);

// Execution
FakeLoadExecutor executor = FakeLoadExecutors.newDefaultExecutor(); 
executor.execute(fakeload);
```

It doesn't provide perfect precision, but it is able to generate quite constant and accurate loads. It is available on Maven Central, so feel free to give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not even possible, because:

1. the way the JVM interprets code (provided it interprets code at all) is implementation-dependent
2. the compiler, and the JVM, may optimize code (in an implementation-dependent manner, of course) so that you may run different bytecodes than the ones in a given .class file.